# Python Split String On A List Of Delimiters, Also Preserve Delimiters

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I am trying to split a string such as `'if (x==5) {'` to be:

```
['if', '(', 'x', '==', '5', ')', '{']
```

I have a list of keywords that I created as my delimiters. Another problem I faced was the order of the delimiters. I would like to split on `'=='` before I split on `'='`

I would like to split on multiple delimiters, yet keep the delimiters as separate elements.

Comment: This sounds a bit more like lexing than just splitting a string. Perhaps a lexing tool will help? http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/

Comment: I think you should have a map of available arguments instead of splitting them as there is no such way as to just split them to a string.

Comment: Thank you for the lexing tool link, I'll try this out!

Comment: I second the lexical parsing notion, as I'm guessing you want `==` to be one token, but `((` may need to be two tokens?

Comment: That's correct @zehnpaard!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dylrei mentioned in the comments, this is lexing. The lexing tool http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ was able to answer my question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.split`.

```
>>> x = 'if (x==5) {'
>>> [i for i in re.split(r'(==)|(\d+)|([(){]|[a-z]+)|\s+', x) if i and i != None ]
['if', '(', 'x', '==', '5', ')', '{']
```

Capturing group will keep up the delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of delimiters like

```
seps= ('(',')','{','}','==','=')
```

You can try this:

```
import re
pattern= r'\s*(%s)\s*'%('|'.join((re.escape(sep) for sep in seps)))
print [token for token in re.split(pattern, 'if (x==5) {') if token]
```

Putting the delimiters inside a capture group (i.e. `(==|=|...)`) causes `re.split` not to discard them.